# Sign error in $\pm$-parts of modular symbols?

Tags: modular-forms, l-functions, p-adic-numbers

I am trying to connect the definition of $\pm$-modular symbols given in [[Pollack, pg. 529]](https://math.bu.edu/people/rpollack/Papers/On_the_padic_Lfunction_of_a_modular_form_at_a_ss_prime.pdf) and [[MTT,pg. 11]](https://eudml.org/doc/143332) to those appearing in  [[Greenberg-Stevens, pg. 200 in #20 here]](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Egreenber/Publications.html), but I can't seem to reconcile a factor of $(-1)^{k-j}$ (see below) showing up. Can someone clarify?

Fix an eigenform $f\in S_k(N,\epsilon)$ and let $K_f$ be its associated number field. Following MTT, Pollack considers the modular integrals
$$
\phi(f,P,r) := 2\pi i \int_{i\infty}^rf(z)P(z)dz
$$
for $P\in \mathbf{C}[z]$ of degree $\leq k-2$, $r\in \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})$, and states that one can find complex periods $\Omega_f^\pm$ such that
$$
\lambda^\pm(f,P(z);a,m) := \frac{\pi i}{\Omega_f^\pm}\bigg(\int_{i\infty}^{a/m}f(z)P(mz-a)dz\pm\int_{i\infty}^{-a/m}f(z)P(mz+a)dz\bigg)\in K_f 
$$

Now let $V_g(\mathbf{C})$ be the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $g$ in variables $X$ and $Y$ over $\mathbf{C}$. Greenberg-Stevens defines the modular symbol $\xi_f\in \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Div}^0(\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})),V_{k-2}(\mathbf{C}))$ by
$$
\xi_f(\{r\}-\{s\}):=2\pi i\int_s^rf(z)(zX+Y)^{k-2}dz\in V_{k-2}(\mathbf{C}).
$$
These modular symbols should be `dual' to the modular integrals defined above in the sense that the integrals should appear as coefficients of the modular symbol. In any case, it should be possible to recover at least $\lambda^\pm(f,z^j;a,m)$ from the modular symbol. The action of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ on maps $\xi:\operatorname{Div}^0(\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q}))\rightarrow V_{k-2}(\mathbf{C})$ is given by
$$
(\xi\mid \gamma)(\{r\}-\{s\})=\xi(\{\gamma r\}-\{\gamma s\})\mid\gamma,
$$
where the action on homogeneous polynomials $P\in V_{k-2}(\mathbf{C})$ is given by
$
P(X,Y)\mid\gamma=P(dX-cY,-bX+aY).
$
Since $\Gamma_1(N)$ is normalized by $\iota=\begin{pmatrix} -1 &0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$, we have a decomposition $\xi_f=\xi_f^++\xi_f^-$ by orthogonal idempotents $(1\pm \iota)/2$. Let's now scale $\xi_f^\pm$ by the same periods $\Omega_f^\pm$ as above and consider the modular symbol $\varphi_f^\pm:=\xi_f^\pm/\Omega_f^\pm$. My hope had been that the coefficients of  $\big(\varphi_f^\pm\mid \gamma \big)(D)$, where $\gamma=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a\\ 0&m\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\{\infty\}-\{0\}$, would allow us to recover the values $\lambda^\pm(f,z^j;a,m)$ of Pollack. This is *nearly* true: expanding everything out, we get that
$$
\big(\varphi_f^\pm\mid \gamma \big)(D)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\binom{k-2}{j}c_{f,j}^\pm(a,m)X^jY^{k-2-j}
$$ where
$$
c_{f,j}^\pm(a,m)=\frac{\pi i}{\Omega_f^\pm}\bigg(\int_{i\infty}^{a/m}f(z)(mz-a)^jdz\pm(-1)^{k-j}\int_{i\infty}^{-a/m}f(z)(mz+a)^jdz\bigg).
$$
Thus, it appears that $c_{f,j}^\pm(a,m)$ only agree with $\lambda^\pm(f,z^j;a,m)$ when $(-1)^{k-j}=1$. Is it possible that Pollack is missing this factor in his definition? That is, one can define a right action of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ on the maps $\phi_f:=\phi(f,\_,\_):\mathbf{C}[z]\times \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})\rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ by setting
$$
(\phi_f\mid\gamma)(P,r) := \phi_f(P(\gamma^*z),\gamma r),
$$
where $\gamma^*$ is the adjugate of $\gamma$. One can then scale and decompose $\phi_f$ by orthogonal idempotents and, doing this, it seems like the $\lambda^\pm$ may indeed be off by a sign... Can someone clarify/verify this?

Comment: Is it possible that both sources are correct? My impression (from a brief scan of your question) is that this looks more like a difference of conventions than an actual error.

Comment: I think you are probably right... I guess the sign doesn't seem to matter much anyways. It seems like re-defining the Pollack $\lambda^\pm$ to include the sign won't change anything except the sign of the period in the interpolation formula (Prop. 2.11 in Pollack's paper). So maybe I should just accept that and stop fussing over it...